# I need to add colors to my appDrawer it is like header part and bottom part

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I created an app drawer and now I need to add color to its background. I managed to add color to the header part now I'm struggling to add to the bottom part. My color choices are RED and Golden Yellow. I am a little bit new to flutter and still learning through by making this kind of projects. And if you have any suggestions regarding making app drawer like this or any other ways I like to know those too.

**Here is my appDrawer.dar code**

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      elevation: 20.0,
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(

              child: Text(
                'Hello Welcome!',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 223, 0, 100),
              )),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.input),
            title: Text('Welcome'),
            onTap: () => {},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
            title: Text('Profile'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Settings'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.border_color),
            title: Text('Feedback'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            title: Text('Logout'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I cold it likes this in my homeScreen.dart file**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true, //this will extend map over the app bar
      drawer: NavDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'MY ORDERS',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25.0),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your widgets with container and give them a color property

```
Container(
color:Colors.red,
child:ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(

              child: Text(
                'Hello Welcome!',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 223, 0, 100),
              )),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.input),
            title: Text('Welcome'),
            onTap: () => {},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
            title: Text('Profile'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Settings'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.border_color),
            title: Text('Feedback'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            title: Text('Logout'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
        ],
      ),
)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much, now I need to add CircleAvatar and text to drawer header. I can add circle but now I need to add text. do you know a method?

Comment: you can search for stack widget or ask new question about that, I can help you at new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your listview into a container and give color to that container. In that way, the color will be applied to the other items as well.

Comment: That's great. Please mark my answer as accepted so others can be benefited from it as well.

Comment: I marked one with the example code because people can get a better idea I think. But it is same as yours .